# Cohomology theories in A.G.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology

I have been studying étale cohomology for a while, and I am beginning to wonder about other ones that were found afterwards. Specifically, I am interested in Weil cohomology theories. My questions are:

1. What is a list of known Weil cohomology theories?
2. Do these other cohomology theories have the same proofs of poincare duality that étale cohomology does?